# odoo.sh ver. 14 WKHTMLTOPDF 0.12.25: Unable to call host printing service (HTTPError). How to circumvent this?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04, odoo-14, odoo.sh

We're using odoo.sh platform with odoo14. The installed wkhtmltopdf is wkhtmltopdf_paas_wrapper 0.12.5, we can't upgrade to 0.12.6 because the access is very limited we cant use 'sudo' to apt-install. To temporarily solve this, we decided to use the 0.12.5 version. But it returns "Unable to call host printing service (HTTPError)" even with the right arguments. I've already tried it with the staging and production server, but still the same result. The ticket I've sent hasn't been replied to yet. This is so frustrating, I'm going bonkers...please help.

here's a screenshot: [image]

ps: unrecognized argument error was intentional so I can display the available args. I've also crossed out the project domain. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, to properly execute the package, it should not have been "wkhtmltopdf" but instead "wkhtmltopdf.bin". I've overridden the ir_actions_report.py to change the package name. Here's the snippet of the original source code:

[image]

They shouldve known better, its a paid platform.